# EF7 - Properties object from entity class are not being filled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity, clean-architecture

Good night!

I am playing with EF7 to learn about it.

I've created the next classes:

```
public class Lawsuit
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Lawsuit identificator.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid LawsuitId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Date time asigned where lawsuit was created.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// First part envolved signature object.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Signature? FirstPartyEnvolved { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// First part envolved signature object.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Signature? SecondPartyEnvolved { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Winner position indicator
        /// </summary>
        public WinnerPosition? WinnerPosition { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Signature
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Id from signature.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// String which saves text received from contract signatures.
        /// </summary>
        public string? Signatures { get; set; }

    }
```

At insert, the data is created correctly at database (SQL Server), but when I try to obtain the data, FirstPartyEnvolved  and SecondPartyEnvolved attributes are empty.

Example of response:

```
[
  {
    "lawsuitId": "6ece06da-d5f9-40e7-a7a3-2816618e7869",
    "dateTimeCreated": "2022-12-12T22:05:24.4717517",
    "firstPartyEnvolved": null,
    "secondPartyEnvolved": null,
    "winnerPosition": 1
  }
]
```

I was checking if the DTO object was not parsing well the data but the problem seems to be at the Entity object

```
public Task Handle()
        {
            var Lawsuites_repo = LawsuitRepository.GetAllLawsuit();
            var Lawsuites = Lawsuites_repo.Select(x =>
                new LawsuitDTO
                {
                    LawsuitId = x.LawsuitId,
                    DateTimeCreated = x.DateTimeCreated,
                    WinnerPosition = x.WinnerPosition ?? 0,
                    FirstPartyEnvolved = x.FirstPartyEnvolved,
                    SecondPartyEnvolved = x.SecondPartyEnvolved
                });

            GetAllLawsuitsOutputPort.Handle(Lawsuites);
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
```

I've tried to changed the Signatures objects for GUID and I am receiving well this data. Seems a problem parsing the object from the EF context to the Entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't detailed what is in your `GetAllLawsuit()` method, but EF does not eager load related entities by default, so you are likely just `ToList()`'ing the content, then the collection will be loaded from the database with null references for the `Signatures`

If you remove the call to `GetAllLawsuit()` and use the `Select` projection directly from the DbContext, then it will work.

You can also force EF to eager load your related entities by using the `Include` extension method in your `GetAllLawsuit` method.

Comment: Hi Chad, that solve my problem, really thanks!

I include the next at GetAllLawsuit()

`return Context.lawsuits.Include("FirstPartyEnvolved").Include("SecondPartyEnvolved");`

Comment: @Barberalex - instead of using the `string` overload for `Include`, use the one which takes a func: `Context.Lawsuits.Include(x => x.FirstPartyEnvolved)`. This way, if ever that property is renamed or changed, your refactoring tools (or the compiler) will pick up the error. Otherwise it will fail at runtime.